# Laravel : The payload is invalid

Tags: laravel, exception, encryption, laravel-5.4

I've upgraded 2 laravel applications on 5.4 few months ago.

Those application were created on 5.1, and I've always follow the upgrade guide 1 month after any release publication.

Since 5.4, I often have this kind of error on POST request :

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException·The payload is invalid


app/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:43App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::handle   
         throw new HttpException(503);
    }
    return $next($request); //line 43
}}
```

Most of the time POST request are ok, but sometimes (around 1 POST request on 1000) I have this error. I fail to reproduce it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the column that you are using to store the encrypted is long enough.

I got this same exception because my 64 encoded string was being strip down due to column length.

keep in mind that the size of the encrypted string can change depending on the size of the text passed through the encrypt function.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But it's under Redis, so I don't think the limit reached .

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the `EncryptCookies` middleware for the route your're accessing. Do you have the 'web' middleware group applied to your routes?

Your Http Kernel should have this in it:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'bindings',
    ],

];
```

Then you can apply 'web' to your routes/groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have the EncryptCookies middleware for those routes. And the 'web' middleware group is applied on those routes.